# фильтрация массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*как отфильтровать один массив по значениям другого и не используемые значения вывести в другой массив - задача с codewars*

```js
function unusedDigits() {
 let finArr = null;
 let newArr = [...arguments].join(''); //массив вводных в строку
 let sortArr = newArr.split(''); //в массив по одному элементу
 console.log(sortArr);
 let dfltArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; //массив для фильтрации вводными

 for (let i = 0; i < sortArr.length; i++) {
  finArr = dfltArr.filter(function(elem) {
      
   if (elem == sortArr[i]) {

    return false;
   } else {
    return true;
console.log('filter', elem);
   }
  });
 }
 console.log(finArr);
}
unusedDigits(2015, 8, 26);
```

Comment: вы лучше бы привели примеры входных данных и желаемого результата.

Comment: надо найти пересечение массивов, и их разность что ли?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference Можете исходники посмотреть как они реализовали

Comment: вот вводные данные     unusedDigits(2015, 8, 26); проверяем на использование чисел от 0  до 9, если числа не используются в водимых данных записываем их в новый массив и выводим это моя функция должна вывести "3479" но выводит чухню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в теле цикла.

Переменная `finArr` постоянно переписывается, однако фильтруется, так же постоянно, только переменная `dfltArr` поэтому в итоге в `finArr` хранится результат фильтрации по последней цифре ввода.

Для решения нужно менять *одну* переменную. Например `dfltArr`

```js
function unusedDigits() {
  let newArr = [...arguments].join(''); //массив вводных в строку
  let sortArr = newArr.split(''); //в массив по одному элементу
  console.log(sortArr);
  let dfltArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; //массив для фильтрации вводными

  for (let i = 0; i < sortArr.length; i++) {
    dfltArr = dfltArr.filter(function(elem) {

      if (elem == sortArr[i]) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(dfltArr);
}
unusedDigits(2015, 8, 26);
```

Альтернативным решением может стать использование `Set`, для хранения уникальных входных элементов, тогда для фильтрации достаточно будет одного вызова filter в котором будет проверяться наличие элемента в `Set`.

Например:

```js
function unusedDigits(...args) {
  let newArr = new Set(args.join('')); //массив уникальных цифр
  return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(elem => !newArr.has(elem.toString()));
}
console.log(unusedDigits(2015, 8, 26));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для разнообразия

```js
function unusedDigits(){
 var azbuka = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], string_ = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments)
 for(var i = 0, length = string_.length; i < length; i++){azbuka[string_[i]] = undefined}
 return Array.prototype.slice.call(azbuka.join(""))
}
 console.log(unusedDigits(2015, [8, 26]));
```