# Фильтровать массив

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
orders: [

    {
      "inet_client_id": 36874,
    },
    {
      "inet_client_id": 36874,
    },
    {
      "inet_client_id": 36874,
    },
    {
      "inet_client_id": 1212,
    },
    {
      "inet_client_id": 36874,
    },
    {
      "inet_client_id": 23543,
    },
    {
      "inet_client_id": 36874,
    },
]
```

Как можно фильтровать массив где `inet_client_id = 36874`, знаю что можно через filter но не пойму как, подскажите пожалуйста

Пробовал `return this.orders.filter(item => item.inet_client_id === '36874')`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [фильтрация массива JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850729/%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-javascript)

Comment: `const filteredOrders = this.orders.filter(item => item.inet_client_id === 36874)` - inet_client_id - тип number, `=== ` - тождество, проверяется еще и тип, '36874' - тип string, а вот так 36874 - number. Так что сравнивать либо `==`, либо с одинаковыми типами, в Вашем случае number'ом

Answer (score 3):

Все правильно. Можно через метод filter сделать. Просто нужно в каждой итерации цикла, извлекать свойство "inet_client_id" и фильтровать его значения.

```
    let newOrders = orders.filter(order => order.inet_client_id === 36874);
    console.log(newOrders)
```

Но, обратите внимание, что у вас orders объявлен, как свойство другого объекта. Для проверки правильности, объявите так:

```
    let orders = [/*ваш код*/]
```